# Time Exceed Alert in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to do time validation condition in excel. If my total time greater than 0:50, am getting text printed like "your have crossed your limit" else "you are good".I used this condition, but it's not working. =IF(K2>TIME(0,50,0),"You have crossed your limit","You are good"). Can anyone help me out on this !?

Comment: you most likely have a data issue in K2, include screen shots of that cell or more examples

Comment: K2 is not a format. It is a column name actually.

Comment: [IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/2v8luyt.png[/IMG]

Comment: Can you provide some details on "it's not working"? Is the cell displaying "You are good" or something else? In your screenshot posted above, the formula is visible rather than the result; is that your issue? Also, for anyone looking at this after me, the corrected image link is: http://oi67.tinypic.com/2v8luyt.jpg

Comment: It's my issue only and the image too. Am not getting the answer. I just pasted the formula which I have used for reference.